# Gunicorn: 127.0.0.1 in use

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

I'm trying to use Django with virtualenv.  I actually got the Django hello world webpage to display with 127.0.0.1:8001.  Later I had to do some minor tweaks and now its giving me this error when I try to launch it again (I ctrl-Z from the previous working gunicorn session so I don't think it is because of that).

```
    user myenv # /opt/myenv/bin/gunicorn -c /opt/myenv/gunicorn_config.py myProject.wsgi
2013-11-02 08:26:37 [27880] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 18.0
2013-11-02 08:26:37 [27880] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('127.0.0.1', 8001)
2013-11-02 08:26:37 [27880] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
2013-11-02 08:26:38 [27880] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('127.0.0.1', 8001)
2013-11-02 08:26:38 [27880] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
2013-11-02 08:26:39 [27880] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('127.0.0.1', 8001)
2013-11-02 08:26:39 [27880] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
^C2013-11-02 08:26:40 [27880] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('127.0.0.1', 8001)
2013-11-02 08:26:40 [27880] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
2013-11-02 08:26:41 [27880] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('127.0.0.1', 8001)
2013-11-02 08:26:41 [27880] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
2013-11-02 08:26:42 [27880] [ERROR] Can't connect to ('127.0.0.1', 8001)
user myenv #
```

Other commands I recently used include:

```
python manage.py syncdb
python manage.py startapp polls
```

I did 'killall python' to make sure they were not the cause.

gunicorn_config.py:

```
command = '/opt/myenv/bin/gunicorn'
pythonpath = '/opt/myenv/myProject
workers = 1
user = 'tim'
```

myProject.wsgi:

```
import os

# os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "myProject.settings"
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myProject.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ctrl+z` halts the process, but does not close it. In consequence it does not release its ports. You can bring the process back with `fg` and then close it properly using `ctrl+c`.

Comment: Update: it worked...I'm confused why though.  I tried fg numerous times, kept outputting the same thing.  Ctrl-C had no effect.  I gave up and then a minute later I tried it again, it magically worked.  Could you please explain what happened?

Comment: The previous process blocking the port was still running, just suspended - that's how `ctrl+z` works. It does **not** close programs. Bringing it back and closing it properly released the port.

Comment: Oh. It seems you edited your comment. If you used `ctrl+z` multiple ties you had multiple suspended processes. `fg` brings back just the last one by default. Not necessarily the one that is blocking the port. You can use `jobs` to list all of them. The bottom line is: in the future just don't use `ctrl+z`.

Answer (score 1):

The error `Connection in use: ...` basically means that the port is still in use even though you exited the server. You need to find who is currently using the port and turn them off. This command can help you find who is there:

```py
$ sudo netstat -nlp | grep :80
```

Then you can sudo kill that process:

```py
sudo fuser -k 8000/tcp
```

You should be able to restart `gunicorn`.

Answer (score 0):

The port 8000 was probably bound and thus unavailable for the connection.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30680508)